# Bug on a terrain generation algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, terrain, perlin-noise

Long story short, the following is based on [mesh generation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64NblGkAabk&t=666s)  and [terrain heights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-0UaeJBumA)

In my code everything seems to be fine. I have redone all of it and the same issue comes up, I don't know why.

All I know is that the last iteration of the Z `for` loop ain't giving the right height.

[image]

I could just set `z-1` and have the game run on the rest of the map

[image]

but I feel that this will ruin my next phase of development and so I beg for hints on where might the issue be.

the code for the perlin noise is as follows

```
public static class PerlinFilter
{
    public static float[] Filter(List<int> keyX, List<int> keyZ, int indexX = 0, int indexZ = 0, int sizeX = 100, int sizeZ = 100, int nOctaves = 3, float fBias = .6f)
    {
        float[] filtered = new float[(sizeX + 1) * (sizeZ + 1)];
        for (int z = indexZ; z < sizeZ; z++)
        {
            for (int x = indexX; x < sizeX; x++)
            {
                float fNoise = 0.0f;
                float fScale = 1.0f;
                float fScaleAcc = 0.0f;

                for (int o = 0; o < nOctaves; o++)
                {
                    int nPitch = sizeZ >> o;
                    int nSampleX1 = x / nPitch * nPitch;
                    int nSampleZ1 = z / nPitch * nPitch;

                    int nSampleX2 = (nSampleX1 + nPitch) % sizeX;
                    int nSampleZ2 = (nSampleZ1 + nPitch) % sizeX;

                    float fBlendX = (float)(x - nSampleX1) / nPitch;
                    float fBlendZ = (float)(z - nSampleZ1) / nPitch;

                    float fSampleT = (1.0f - fBlendX) * keyX[nSampleZ1 * sizeX + nSampleX1] + fBlendX * keyZ[nSampleZ1 * sizeZ + nSampleX2];
                    float fSampleB = (1.0f - fBlendX) * keyX[nSampleZ2 * sizeX + nSampleX1] + fBlendX * keyZ[nSampleZ2 * sizeZ + nSampleX2];

                    fNoise += (fBlendZ * (fSampleB - fSampleT) + fSampleT) * fScale;
                    fScaleAcc += fScale;
                    fScale /= fBias;
                }
                filtered[z * sizeX + x] = fNoise / fScaleAcc;
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
}
```

and the code for the mesh is as follows:

```
void Generate(bool flat)
{
    vertices = new Vector3[(x + 1) * (z + 1)];

    for (int i = 0, iz = 0; iz <= z; iz++)
    {
        for (int ix = 0; ix <= x; ix++, i++)
        {
            if (flat)
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(ix, 0, iz);
            else
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(ix, PerlinHeight(ix, iz), iz);
        }
    }

    triangles = new int[x * z * 6];

    for (int tris = 0, vert = 0, iz = 0; iz < z; iz++, vert++)
    {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < x; ix++, vert++, tris += 6)
        {
            triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
            triangles[tris + 1] = vert + x + 1;
            triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
            triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
            triangles[tris + 4] = vert + x + 1;
            triangles[tris + 5] = vert + x + 2;
        }
    }
}

public int PerlinHeight(int _x, int _z) => (int)(keyPerlin[_z * x + _x] * 1f);
```

`keyPerlin` is the result of the PerlinFilter.Filter.

If it becomes obvious that I need to add more code here let me know, this was done a few months ago, and I have been working on other parts of the game while accepting the `z-1` workaround, but at this point I really need to sort this issue out.

Comment: where is the reference to get `the right height.`

Comment: the image shows one line at 0. the height is being assigned to a vector in the Generate method by the PerlinHeight method.

Answer (score 1):

In your noise filter generation you do

```
float[] filtered = new float[(sizeX + 1) * (sizeZ + 1)];
for (int z = indexZ; z < sizeZ; z++)
{
    for (int x = indexX; x < sizeX; x++)
    {
        ...
```

=> You don't fill the complete array with valid values! The last row for `z== SizeZ` and `x==SizeX` keeps the default value `0`.

While in the mesh you do

```
vertices = new Vector3[(x + 1) * (z + 1)];

for (int i = 0, iz = 0; iz <= z; iz++)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix <= x; ix++, i++)
    {
        ...
```

=> You set the last row of vertices all to `0`.

Comment: well i have been thinkering with that a lot, but one thing that you are missing is that is only on the `z` axis that the loop fails, and if i do ` z<=sizeZ` it breaks. I assume is ArrayIndexOutOfBBounds but on unity logs it just goes to complain about other script that the floor is missing.